# I/O Reading from a file

Tags: python

I'm using code like this:

```
f = open('boo.txt')
line = f.readline()
print line
f.close()
```

How can I make it read a different line or a random line every time I open the script, instead of just printing out the first line?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
f = open('boo.txt')
lines = [line for line in f]
f.close()
import random
selectedline = random.choice(lines)
print (selectedline)
```

Comment: You can replace last line with more elegant `selectedline = random.choice(lines)`

Answer (score 6):

Another way with use of context managers:

```
import random

with open("boo.txt", "r") as f:
    print random.choice(f.readlines())
```

Answer (score 2):

```
f = open('boo.txt')
import random
print random.choice(f.readlines())
```

Comment: It is better to close file after.